# Change grid column filter in SmartGWT

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

If you create a custom [DataSource](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/data/DataSource.html) in SmartGWT, is it possible to remove a field filter instead of hiding it entirely from the grid columns?

As seen here:

[image]

The *Country code* field exists, but is **hidden** in the above image.

**Clarification:** I want to hide the *Country code* field at the start, but still have it visible in the *Columns* context menu. If you use `setHidden(true)` the field disappears from the *Columns* menu above.

Example code:

```
public class MyDataSource extends DataSource {

    public MyDataSource() {
        DataSourceField countryField = new DataSourceIntegerField("country", "Country code");
        // TODO Find a method that disables the filter, aka hides but not removes the field from the grid.
        countryField.setHidden(true); // Completely hides/removes the field, not desireable.
        countryField.setCanFilter(true); // Doesn't seem to change anything. 
        addField(countryField);

        // Other fields...
    }

}
```

How would this be achieved in a ListGrid with the above DataSource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I fully understood the question.

Are you looking for a way to ***hide*** the "Country code" option from the *Columns* context menu? You can do that by declaring 
[`ListGridField.setCanHide(false)`](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/grid/ListGridField.html#setCanHide%28java.lang.Boolean%29) to the corresponding ListGridField.

```
ListGridField countryCode = new ListGridField("countryCode");
countryCode.setHidden(true);
countryCode.setCanHide(false); // won't be shown in the context menu
```

Or, are you trying to disable ***filtering***?

If so, does the user have to have the option to see the country code column in some cases?
If not, you can just leave the `MyDataSource` as it is and define only those `ListGridFields` that you want the user to see.

```
ListGrid grid = new ListGrid();
ListGridField country = new ListGridField("country");
ListGridField capital = new ListGridField("capital");
ListGridField continent = new ListGridField("continent");
// no countryCode here
grid.setFields(country, capital, continent);
```

The underlying country code attribute is still available in the code, eg. via `record.getAttribute("countryCode");`, it's just not shown in the ListGrid.

Alternatively, you can define the filtering on grid level with [`ListGridField.canFilter(Boolean canFilter)`](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/grid/ListGridField.html#setCanFilter%28java.lang.Boolean%29).

```
ListGridField countryCode = new ListGridField("countryCode ");
countryCode.setCanFilter(false);
```

**EDIT:**

So, don't set the hidden attribute in the datasource, but instead directly to the `ListGridField`.

DataSource

```
public class MyDataSource extends DataSource {

  public MyDataSource() {
    DataSourceField countryCode = new DataSourceStringField("countryCode", "Country code");
    DataSourceField country = new DataSourceStringField("country", "Country");
    DataSourceField capital = new DataSourceStringField("capital", "Capital");
    DataSourceField continent = new DataSourceStringField("continent", "Continent");

    setFields(countryCode, country, capital, continent);
  }
}
```

ListGrid

```
ListGrid grid = new ListGrid();
ListGridField countryCode = new ListGridField("countryCode");
countryCode.setHidden(true);
countryCode.setCanHide(true); // I don't think this is even necessary.
ListGridField country = new ListGridField("country");
ListGridField capital = new ListGridField("capital");
ListGridField continent = new ListGridField("continent");
grid.setFields(countryCode, country, capital, continent);
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: None of those situations; I want to hide the 'Country code' field at the start, but still have it visible in the 'Columns' context menu. Which doesn't happen if you use setHidden, or setCanHide. E.g. so that 'Country code' is hidden from the start, but so that it can still be turned on via the 'Columns' menu. Hope that made some sense.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! I didn't assume that the DataSource fields != ListGrid fields, yet it's so obvious now.